# Jekyll extracting filename from url with Ruby

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to extract the file name from a url on Jekyll using this ruby snippet:

```
{% assign filename = page.url.split('/')[-1] | replace: '.html', '.md' %}
```

If I just use:

```
{% assign filename = page.url | replace: '.html', '.md' %}
```

I get back the url with the replaced file type but my `.split('/')[-1]` doesn't seem to work.

I tried running the following in standalone ruby to ensure my syntax was right, and it returned `bird` as expected:

```
"cat/dog/b­ird".split­('/')[-1]
```

Why doesn't the same syntax work in my Jekyll instance? Is it that `page.url` isn't a string, or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is mixing ruby code with Liquid tags.

To extract the filename from a url in Jekyll you can use just pure Liquid template filters, using the equivalents of what you tried:

- `.split­('/')` -> `| split: '/'`
- `[-1]` -> `| last`

As an example with a custom URL:

```
{% assign url_example = "cat/dog/bird.html" %}
{% assign filename = url_example | split: '/' | last | replace: '.html', '.md' %}
{{filename}}
```

outputs:

```
bird.md
```